# Geoprocessing Service works in ArcMap but not via Server Manager or JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service

I've published a simple geoprocessing service that takes an uploaded zip file and unzips it. The geoprocessing service was published with "uploads" enabled. I have also enabled "Info" level messaging, but nothing gets logged so that's been useless. When I run the GP service in ArcMap, it runs perfectly fine and does what I expect it to do. When I try running from the rest API, I get a failure message. When I try running from the JavaScript API, I get a failure message also that's a little more detailed, it says I have an Invalid URL but I'm not sure what URL it's evaluating...

Rest API input (I'm not entirely sure I'm inputting it right so it could be that):
[image]

After clicking "Submit Job (POST)", I get this:
[image]

In the JavaScript API, this is my code:

```
require([
"esri/map",
"esri/request",
"esri/arcgis/utils",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
"esri/tasks/Geoprocessor",
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/on",
"dojo/domReady!"
],
function(
Map,
esriRequest,
arcgisUtils,
FeatureLayer,
Geoprocessor,
dom,
on
) {

var map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "hybrid",
  center: [-77.069, 36.950],
  zoom: 14
});

var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://www.myurl.org/xxx/rest/services/HbMonitoringTest/HabitatData/MapServer/1");

map.addLayer(featureLayer);

gp = new Geoprocessor("https://www.myurl.org/xx/rest/services/Web_Map_GP_Services/ZipTest/GPServer");

on(dom.byId("upload"), "click", upload);
function upload(){
  //upload the zip file and get back the itemID (via uploadSucceeded)
  var upload = esri.request({  
    url: "https://www.myurl.org/xxx/rest/services/Web_Map_GP_Services/ZipTest/GPServer/uploads/upload", 
    form: dojo.byId("uploadForm"),  
    content: {f: 'json'},  
    handleAs: 'json',
  }).then(uploadSucceeded, uploadFailed);  
}

function uploadSucceeded(response) {  
  var itemID = response["item"].itemID;  
  console.log("File upload successful, item ID: ", itemID);
  var params = {"Input_Zip_File": "{'itemID':" +itemID+ "}" };
  gp.submitJob(params, gpJobComplete, gpJobStatus, function(error){
    console.log(error.jobStatus + '(' + error.jobId + '):' + dojo.toJson(error));
  });
}

function gpJobComplete(result){
  console.log(result.jobStatus + '(' + result.jobId + ')')
}

function gpJobStatus(result){
  console.log(result.jobStatus + '(' + result.jobId + '):' + dojo.toJson(message));
}

function uploadFailed(response){
  console.log("Failed: ", response);
}

});
```

For the error I get a HTTP 400 error, "Invalid URL":
[image]

Comment: At the REST API (services endpoint), you can't put the path in like that, try this:  `{'url':'https://www.myurl.org/myfile.zip'}`

Comment: @KHibma - Thank you, that's really helpful to know for the future! I actually found my stupid mistake in the javascript code, my geprocessor doesn't include the tool name at the end of the URL. Got everything working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why my javascript wasn't working. The geoprocessor I set up doesn't include the tool name at the end of the URL, which is why it was invalid. Here's what that line should be:

```
gp = new Geoprocessor("https://URL/servername/rest/services/Web_Map_GP_Services/ZipTest/GPServer/ZipTest");
```

To run from Rest API, I first had to go through the "Upload" task to create an item ID:
[image]
[image]

Next, I had to go to the task and submit a job with the URL generated with that item ID:
[image]

This resulted in success!

Comment: Actually, after you've uploaded it to the uploads end point, you could do it by reference like:  `{'itemID': "longitemid"}`